# Can't run CUDA nor OpenCL on GeForce 540M

Tags: cuda, opencl, nvidia, optimus

I have problem running samples provided by Nvidia in their GPU Computing SDK (there's a library of compiled sample codes).

For cuda I get message "No CUDA-capable device is detected", for OpenCL there's error from function that should find OpenCL capable units.

I have installed all three parts from Nvidia to develop with OpenCL - devdriver for win7 64bit v.301.27, cuda toolkit 4.2.9 and gpu computing sdk 4.2.9.

I think this might have to do with Optimus technology that reroutes output from Nvidia GPU to Intel to render things (this notebook has also Intel 3000HD accelerator), but in Nvidia control pannel I set to use high performance Nvidia GPU, set power profile to prefer maximum performance and for PhysX I changed from automatic selection to Nvidia processor again. Nothing has changed though, those samples won't run (not even those targeted for GF8000 cards).

I would like to play somewhat with OpenCL and see what it is capable of but without ability to test things it's useless. I have found some info about this on forums, but it was mostly about linux users where you need Bumblebee to access Nvidia GPU. There's no such problem on Windows however, drivers are better and so you can access it without dark magic (or I thought so until I found this problem).

Comment: What does device query say? The same? Or does this result come from device query? More important: Did you read [NVIDIA CUDA Developer Guide for NVIDIA Optimus Platforms](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/docs/CUDA_Developer_Guide_for_Optimus_Platforms.pdf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this has proven to be totally crazy solution. I was thinking if something isn't hooking between the hardware and application and only thing that came to my mind was AV software. I'm using Comodo with sandbox and Defense+ on and after turning them off I could run all those samples. What's more, only Defense+ needs to be turned off.

Now I just think about how much apps could have been blocked from accessing that GPU..

Answer (score 2):

My laptop has a GeForce 540M as well, in an Optimus configuration since my Sandy Bridge CPU also has Intel's integrated graphics.  To run CUDA codes, I have to:

1. Install NVIDIA Driver
2. Go to NVIDIA Control Panel
3. Click 3D Settings -> Manage 3D Settings -> Global Settings
4. In the Preferred Graphics processor drop down, select "High-performance NVIDIA processor"
5. Apply the settings

Note that the instructions above apply the settings for all applications, so you don't have to worry about CUDA errors any more.  But it will drain more battery.

Here is a [video recap](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRi9U3x1cgE) as well.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as you can see in my question, I already set the global settings in control panel to use Nvidia GPU (high performance processor). Also I've installed most recent developer drivers. Well maybe I can run OpenCL, I was just discouraged to code something when I can't run official sample codes.. Did you try running those? They come with GPU computing sdk..

Comment: Maybe the official codes are not considering the Optimus platform.

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely because of the architecture of Optimus. So I'd suggest you to read  
[NVIDIA CUDA Developer Guide for NVIDIA Optimus Platforms](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/docs/CUDA_Developer_Guide_for_Optimus_Platforms.pdf), especially the section "Querying for a CUDA Device" which addresses this issue, I believe.